# XAML - MenuFlyoutItem attached to a ListView doesn't work in WP8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, relaycommand, flyout

I develop an **Universal app** that uses the **MVVM-Lght toolkit**.

On a page, I show a list of comments. I would like that an user could add a new comment, and edit or delete its existing comments.

For adding new comment, I use an **AppBarButton** on the **CommandBar** and it works fine.

For editing and deleting the existing comments, I would like to display a **MenuFlyout** that offers 2 items: "***edit***" and "***delete***". I can display the **MenuFlyout** but nothing happens when I click on its items...

[image]

Here is my concerned **xaml** code:

```
    <ListView x:Name="myCommentaires" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComment}"
              ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,19,12"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- 1. Author -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding name}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                        <!-- 2. Date -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextAlignment="Right"
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- 3. Content -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding content}"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Margin="0" 
                               Foreground="Black"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    <!-- MenuFlyout - with Commands -->
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"
                                            Command="{Binding EditCommentCommand}"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                                            Command="{Binding DeleteCommentCommand}"/>
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <!-- Behavior -->
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                            <local:OpenFlyoutAction />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

And its attached **code-behind**:

```
    public class OpenFlyoutAction : DependencyObject, IAction
    {
        public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
        {
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And this is my **ViewModel** code:

```
    // RelaydCommands declarations
    ...
    public RelayCommand AddCommentCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand EditCommentCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand DeleteCommentCommand { get; set; }
    ...

    // RelayCommands are affected in the constructor
    ...
    AddCommentaireCommand = new RelayCommand(AddCommentaire);
    EditCommentaireCommand = new RelayCommand(EditCommentaire);
    DeleteCommentaireCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteCommentaire);
    ...

    // Methods related to the RelayCommands
    private async void AddComment()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateTo<EditCommentViewModel>(this, new object[] { _article, _titleStructure.Title }, true); 
    }

    private async void EditComment()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateTo<EditCommentViewModel>(this, new object[] { _article, _titleStructure.Title, SelectedComment }, true);
    }

    private async void DeleteComment()
    {
        var test = SelectedComment;
    }
```

I don't meet any problem with the "***AddComment***" method, which is called from the **AppBarButton**, but I never enter in the methods "***EditComment***" and "***DeleteComment***" whereas I place breakpoints.

I also tried to replace the **Command** of the **MenuFlyoutItem** by a **CallMethodAction**, but it doesn't change anything:

```
    <!-- MenuFlyout - with CallMethodAction -->
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                </Style>
            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                        <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="EditComment" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                        <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="DeleteComment" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

***=> Could anyone say me what is wrong?***

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your `flyout` inside your listview, hence the datacontext is set to the `Comments` property on your `ViewModel`.
Meaning that the 2 commands you are using are not found!

To fix this, you need to reference your page datacontext and use that to locate the commands.

Give your `<Page>` a name like `x:Name="PageRoot"` and change the binding of the commands to

`{Binding ElementName=PageRoot, Path=DataContext.EditCommentCommand}`

Comment: Thanks, it works and I can now enter in the DeleteComment method, but I don't know how to get the clicked comment for editing or deleting it...