# How to test the value of a ListView.ItemTemplate before showing a MenuFlyout

Tags: xaml, listview, mvvm-light, win-universal-app, flyout

I develop an **Universal app** using **MVVM-Light**, and I need to manage comments on a page.
On this page, I show a List of comments, and I want to show a **MenuFlyout** that allows user to edit or delete its comments:

[image]

By following this link [Using a Behavior to open Attached Flyouts in Windows 8.1 Store apps](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/using-a-behavior-to-open-attached-flyouts-in-winows-81-store-apps/), I managed to show the **MenuFlyout** when an Item of the **ListView** is tapped.

***=> But I would like to display the MenuFlyout only if the user is the author of the selected comment...
Is there a way to do this?***

Here is my **XAML**:

```
    <ListView x:Name="myComments" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComment}"
              ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,19,12"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- 1. Author -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding name}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                        <!-- 2. Date -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextAlignment="Right"
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- 3. Content -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding content}"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Margin="0" 
                               Foreground="Black"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    <!-- MenuFlyout - with Commands -->
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"
                                            Command="Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=DataContext.EditCommentCommand}"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                                            Command="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommentCommand}"/>

                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <!-- Behavior -->
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                            <local:OpenFlyoutAction />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

And here is the **code-cehind**:

```
    public class OpenFlyoutAction : DependencyObject, IAction
    {
        public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
        {
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

***=> Is it possible to show the FlyoutBase directly in the ViewModel instead of the code-behind?***

I've first created another topic because I encountered a problem on **MenuFLyoutItem** and **Command**: [XAML - MenuFlyoutItem attached to a ListView doesn't work in WP8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852198/xaml-menuflyoutitem-attached-to-a-listview-doesnt-work-in-wp8-1/)
Tell me if I have to continue on this another topic and delete this one.

Comment: I would guess you have 2 options, 1 work with a DataTemplateSelector and use 2 different datatemplates ( one with and one without flyout ) or 2 pass a param ( a bool like IsAuthor that is filled through your model/viewmodel ) to the eventtrigger so you can validate that to actually show or not show the flyout in the execute method

Comment: @Depechie I try to use a DataTemplateSelector, but it doesn't work: the ListView now shows items as "SolutionName.Model.Comment" instead of using a DataTemplate. I give you more details in an answer, cause I can't post code here.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to the answer at Depechie on the **DataTemplateSelector**, here is what I've done:

I create a **DataTemplateSelector** class called "***CommentsTemplateSelector***":

```
    public class CommentsTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate UserComment { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate NoUserComment { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
        {
            Commentaire comment = (Commentaire)item;
            if (comment.isAuthor)
                return UserComment;
            else
                return NoUserComment;
        }
    }
```

I declare this **DataTemplateSelector** and its associated templates in the page's resources:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- TemplateSelectors -->
        <ts:CommentsTemplateSelector x:Key="CommentsTemplateSelector" />
        <!-- DataTemplates -->
        <!-- UserComment : with MenuFlyout -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserComment">
            <Border Tapped="Border_Tapped">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,19,12"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- 1. Author -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding name}"
                                   ... />
                        <!-- 2. Date -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}"
                                   ... />
                    </Grid>
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
                <!-- MenuFlyout -->
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"
                                        Command="{Binding ElementName=CommentsPage, Path=DataContext.EditCommentCommand}" />
                        </MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                                        Command="{Binding ElementName=CommentsPage, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommentCommand}" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <local:OpenFlyoutAction />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- NoUserComment : without MenuFlyout -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NoUserComment">
            <Border Tapped="Border_Tapped" Background="Red">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,19,12"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- 1. Author -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{Binding name}"
                               ... />
                        <!-- 2. Date -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}"
                               ... />
                    </Grid>
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        ...
    <Page.Resources>
```

Finally, I affected the **ItemTemplateSelector** of my **ListView** to the DataTemplateSelector:

```
    <ListView x:Name="myCommentaires" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Commentaires}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CommentsTemplateSelector}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommentaire, Mode=TwoWay}"
              ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
```

When I launch the app, I go into the class "***CommentsTemplateSelector***" and it works fine, but the **ListView** only shows the model name for each items:

[image]

***So I think there is a Binding  problem in the DataTemplates but what is it?***

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked after monvig the templates from the page's resources into **ListView.ItemTemplateSelector**:

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <ts:CommentsTemplateSelector>
            <!-- UserComment : with MenuFlyout -->
            <ts:CommentsTemplateSelector.UserComment>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Tapped="Border_Tapped">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,19,12"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- 1. Author -->
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{Binding name}"
                                           ... />
                                <!-- 2. Date -->
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}"
                                           ... />
                            </Grid>
                            ...
                        </StackPanel>
                        <!-- MenuFlyout -->
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"
                                                Command="{Binding ElementName=CommentsPage, Path=DataContext.EditCommentCommand}" />
                                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                                                Command="{Binding ElementName=CommentsPage, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommentCommand}" />
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                <local:OpenFlyoutAction />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ts:CommentsTemplateSelector.UserComment>
            <!-- NoUserComment : without MenuFlyout -->
            <ts:CommentsTemplateSelector.NoUserComment>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Red">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,19,12"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- 1. Author -->
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                       Text="{Binding name}"
                                       ... />
                                <!-- 2. Date -->
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}"
                                       ... />
                            </Grid>
                            ...
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ts:CommentsTemplateSelector.UserComment>
        </ts:CommentsTemplateSelector>
    <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
```

I don't know why it hasn't worked into the page's resources as I found some samples like this...